# Getting information about the files opened/used by running processes

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a module which gets all running processes as they started.
I am using following class to get all started processes as they arrive:

`Win32_ProcessStartTrace`

I am trying to get all the file paths opened/used by processes. For example, when I am opening a text file with notepad, I get notepad process but I am trying to find the file that is opened with notepad.

I am using following line to get process information but only information I find is about the process but not about the files used by the process.

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
```

Is there a way I can get path of files opened/used by process? I did check google and referred stackoverflow but have not found a solution.

Comment: get a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/OpenedFileFinder.aspx?fid=422864&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=2277170)

Comment: Yes hook createfIle, use some dll injection technique, However this si way too broad for stackoverflow Q & A format